# how to bind checkbutton with a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to use the **checkbutton** widget along with a boolean variable. When I used a script *without* a class - it worked, but when I wrote the application as a class, it did not. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Checkbutton, Button

class MyFrame(Frame):   
    def __init__(self, parent):     
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.test01 = False

        checkbutton = Checkbutton(parent, text='check it', variable=self.test01, command=self.testcheck)
        checkbutton.var = self.test01
        checkbutton.pack()

        testbutton = Button(parent, text='check test', command=self.testcheck)
        testbutton.pack()
        self.parent.title('Checkbutton test')


    def testcheck(self):

        print('Check test: ' + str(self.test01))

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: The checkbutton problem]

In the picture you can see terminal with the output of the program. In the case in the picture the app was started and every combination of toggling the check button and pressing test button gave no results.

I tried to linked the variable in the constructor, then after the button was constructed, and both - with no results.

Comment: you can't use a normal variable as the value of the `variable` option. You have to use one of the special tkinter variables (`StringVar`, `BooleanVar`, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I've read the answer below (1), and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BooleanVar`. To obtain the states uses `{variable}.get()`.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Checkbutton, Button, BooleanVar

class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.test01 = BooleanVar()
        checkbutton = Checkbutton(parent, text='check it',
        variable=self.test01, command=self.testcheck)

        checkbutton.pack()

        testbutton = Button(parent, text='check test', command=self.testcheck)
        testbutton.pack()
        self.parent.title('Checkbutton test')


    def testcheck(self):

        print('Check test: ' + str(self.test01.get()))

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc! You posted so precise answer and exact solution, with changes that were necessary -- it worked! Best regards :)

Comment: @khaz 
If my answer helped you, you could mark it as correct.